# collective noun/verb agreement

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Please someone who specializes as a grammarian answer this:
The family is/are pursuing their individual interests.  Could you also give me the authoritative source for the answer!!!

Comment: While you peruse those answers  and the near duplicates linked to above, keep in mind that in American English it is almost always going to be *the family is*.

Comment: I've known Americans who don't usually subscribe to notional agreement say that 'The family is pursuing their individual interests.' is unacceptable. With notional agreement, 'The family are pursuing their individual interests.'  is unremarkable, and the major reason why many prefer notional agreement.